# Separting ListItems in next Activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

I am passing ListItems in an ArrayList to another activity. On the next Activity the ListItems are all together on one row. The first activity can send 1 ListItem or many, many ListItems. I am going to send the ListItems in the second activity to a database. They all go into same column in the database but their values must be separated. How do I separate the ListItems so that when they go into the database EACH one (not the combined value of the list)can be retrieved later.

ACTIVITY A

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.salelistitems,R.id.saleNotes,listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This part is working fine, just showing that I sent

```
.putStringArrayListExtra("list", listItems);
```

ACTIVITY B

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.salelistitems,R.id.saleNotes,listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
    al = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("listItems");
    if (al != null) 
    {
    listItems.add(al+"");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I am sending numbers and I don't want the value (1,2,3,4) entered into the database
I want the values

1 (to database column)

2 (to database column)

3 (to database column)

4 (to database column)

I hope that makes it clear. Thanks

Comment: ???.... What does your mean. Activity A to Activity B and database . What you want to say buddy!!!, Please give answer in simple way

Comment: ListItems go from Activity A to B. ListItems go from Activity B to database. On Activity A ListItems are on different rows like they should be. When sent to Activity B ListItems are all together on one row. If I then send to database I will have all together ListItems when I want them seperated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] items = al.split(",");
```

Comment: Is this for entry into database or Activity B ArrayList

Comment: `al` is the ArrayList in Activity B. After this, you can save in your database each element from `items`

example:
`al = "1,2,3,4" => items = { "1", "2", "3", "4" }`

Comment: Where do I put that? Everywhere I put it I get an error.        public void addNewsale(View view) {
HashMap<String, String> queryValues =  new  HashMap<String, String();
final TextView saleNotes =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.saleNotes);
queryValues.put("saleNotes", saleNotes.getText().toString());
controller.insertsale(queryValues);
this.callHomeActivity(view);
 }

Comment: The method split(String) is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>. That when I try to put it with my intent. Yes im a Noob :) I guess I'm asking how do I define the method split(String)

Comment: Sorry! Try `al.get(0).split(",")`

Comment: Before using my solution, what did `al` contain?

Comment: I posted the question again in a slightly different way. I have the A to B intent working. I just cant get to database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486899/how-to-send-listview-contents-to-sqlite-database