# How to send ListView contents to Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-listview

ACTIVITY A

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.salelistitems,R.id.saleNotes,listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This part is working fine, just showing that I sent

```
.putStringArrayListExtra("list", listItems);
```

ACTIVITY B

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.salelistitems,R.id.saleNotes,list);
setListAdapter(adapter);

ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
al = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("listItems");
if (al != null) 
{
listItems.add(al+"");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And how I send to database from Activity B

```
public void addNewsale(View view) {
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues =  new  HashMap<String, String>();
    final TextView saleNotes =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.saleNotes);
    queryValues.put("saleNotes", saleNotes.getText().toString());
    controller.insertsale(queryValues);
    this.callHomeActivity(view);
}
```

The List is coming to Activity B in one row all together, In Activity A each row had an item.
I do not know how to separate the ListViews Items. The problem is saleNotes can be 1 ListItem or 100 ListItems. I don't want to send information as a TextView because it will go in database as [4 cars 3 houses 1 banana] but instead I want

4 cars

3 houses

1 banana

***Thank You OKS 16***
    This sends the information from Activity A to B correctly

```
ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
al = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
if (al != null){
for(String item:al){
listItems.add(item);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

But how do I send to database? It's still a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
  `for(String item:al){

listitems.add(item)

}`

Comment: Do you know how to send the items to the database?

Comment: Follow this guide to create your db classes. We can help if you ran into specific issues in implementation. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: My database is ready. The column is called saleNotes. I just want the listItems to go in as individual values instead one big value. My User can choose a Pizza with Pepp and Mushroom. As it is now if I include TextView saleNotes then when I pull the info my the database later into another ListView it will read PizzaPeppMushroom which is not what I want. I'm trying to get 1 Pizza then 1 pep then 1 Mushroom

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem fully . You can store salesInfo like this Pizza#Pepp#Mushroom, and when you retrieve split it using # as separator.